# Saving C# enumeration as string instead of int in ElasticSearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, enums, attributes, nest

I used to have String attribute on class properties of type enumeration in Elastic Search 2.0 so that enumeration value to be stored as string rather than integer:

```
public enum PaperType
{
    A4 = 0,
    A3 = 1
}
```

and class to be stored as document in ElasticSearch

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "Paper")]
public class Paper
{  
  [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
  public PaperType Type { get; set; }
}
```

So in Type would be stored as A3 or A4 rather than 0 or 1.

in ElasticSearch 5, these attributes have changed,

How could I achieve the same behavior in ElasticSearch 5 or what attribute and how it should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/attribute-mapping.html) in the documentation; you're likely looking to map them as `Keyword` types.

If you want to save all `enum` as string, you can add the Json.Net `StringEnumConverter` to the [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/modifying-default-serializer.html) to use for any type that is an enum.